# Which kind of relations are considered incestuous in Judaism?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, marriage, family-members

Specifically what kind of relationships are defined as incestuous in Judaism? I am guessing that it is forbidden to marry one's parents/children or siblings but what about other relations like first cousins?

Also, what is the specific source (is this outlined Biblically or rabbinically)?

Comment: See Leviticus 18 and 20

Comment: Cousins could get married, but today it's kind of gross.

Comment: @AL Why is it gross?

Comment: Fixed Point, welcome to Mi Yodeya, by which I hope you're attracted, rather than repelled.

Comment: Let me echo @msh210's welcome and add that I hope you'll look around the site and find other material you can relate to, perhaps including our 180 other [tag:marriage] questions.

Comment: @FixedPoint It's just not so common today. Marrying cousins in modern culture (except in some places) is unusual, like marrying a friend you grew up with. But that's just subjective. It also tends to produce less healthy offspring than a marriage with greater genetic diversity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Mother (B)
- Mother's mother (R)
- Mother's mother's... mother (R)
- Mother's father's mother (R)
- Father's mother (R)
- Father's mother's... mother (R)
- Father's father's mother (R)
- Father's wife (B)
- Father's father's wife (R)
- Father's father's... father's wife (R)
- Mother's father's wife (R)
- Father's mother's father's wife (R; some permit)
- Father's paternal brother's wife (B)
- Father's maternal brother's wife (R)
- Mother's brother's wife (R)
- Sister (B)
- Non-Jewish sister (R; some permit)
- Daughter (B)
- Daughter's daughter (B)
- Son's daughter (B)
- All further female direct descendants (R; some permit)
- Wife's daughter (B)
- Wife's daughter's daughter (B)
- Wife's son's daughter (B)
- All of wife's further female direct descendants (R; some permit)
- Wife's mother (B)
- Wife's mother's mother (B)
- Wife's father's mother (B)
- All of wife's further female direct ancestors (R; some permit)
- Father's sister (B)
- Mother's sister (B)
- Son's wife (B)
- Son's son's wife (R)
- Son's son's... son's wife (R)
- Daughter's son's wife (R)
- Brother's wife (B)
- Wife's sister while wife is alive (B)

<sup>(B = biblically prohibited, R = rabbinically prohibited)</sup>

Source: Shulchan Aruch Even HaEzer 15

Comment: Great answer (and +1), but you might want to add that one's niece is not a forbidden relationship - and was traditionally considered a good match. You didn't say that it *was* prohibited, but someone scanning the list might fail to notice that it's not mentioned.

Comment: do the ellipses mean that it doesn't matter how many generations?

Comment: @Menachem Yes.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​